# Select an Ext.Picker field by default

Tags: sencha-touch

I've created a Picker in a form in my sencha app. The field is empty by default. How do I set it to be selected on the first item in the data array?

Answer (score 0):

It automatically selects the first item in data array (node 0) ... if the first item is empty and you want it to be on the 2nd item you can (assuming a the component variable is called `picker`) use `picker.items.items[0].setSelectedNode(1)`

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange. Node 0 isn't empty, but it's still not showing it by default.